# Какой знак препинания следует поставить в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, приложение

Скажите, пожалуйста, в данном предложении необходимо тире или запятая?

> А это мой хороший друг (–/,) гитара для левшей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует поставить тире:

*А это мой хороший друг – гитара для левшей.*

Словосочетание «***гитара для левшей***» является приложением, относящимся к определяемому слову «***друг***».

> 10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется **тире:**
>     <...>
>     **2)** перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение: *Я не слишком люблю это дерево — **осину*** (Т.) <...> *На маяке жил только сторож — **старый глухой швед*** (Пауст.); *Стоял чудесный апрельский день — **лучшее время в Арктике*** (Горб.)...

Источник: [**Обособленные приложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Александр, а здесь тоже тире ставится: "А это мой хороший друг () Вася". Вроде бы пояснение в конце предложения. Вообще-то это вопрос к Розенталю на тему точности формулировок, а вы уж за него... :) И еще по поводу знака  ...?  можете что-нибудь сказать?

Comment: @Sharon С ударением только на Васе можно вообще ничего не ставить, с короткой паузой – запятая, с подчёркнутой – тире. :)) А вот с гитарой запятая не катит, даже зрительно. // Вы, скорее всего, видели переписку с Нектоидом под его конкурсом. В правилах такое сочетание не указано, но и нет запрета, то есть если перед вопр./воскл. знаком в цитате пропускаются слова, то многоточие ставится перед ним и его точка по идее не сжирается знаком. Я так это понимаю. Только насчёт пробела между ними не знаю (вот сейчас смотрю: вроде даже без него между точкой вопроса и соседней расстояние больше).

Comment: А это мой хороший друг – Вася.  Тире и увеличенная пауза выглядят странно, с какой-то коннотацией (на многоточие похоже).  Смысл паузы  неясен.  Нормально выглядит запятая или отсутствие знака. Я вообще сомневаюсь, что одиночное приложение позволительно обособлять тире. "Осина" здесь особый случай, там местоимение "это" требует расшифровки.  А знак ...?  мне реально поставили в тексте.  Но разрешения на него я нигде не видела. Про точки, которые то сжираются, то нет,  я вообще не понимаю.  От чего это зависит, и это условность или что? Вот как оценить грамотность такой записи?

Comment: Бог с ним, с Васей (согласен, что тире чересчур, хотя тоже возможно). А гитара не одиночная, вы ж не против тире? Оно ведь сюда лучше подходит? // Точка (или две) в многоточии поглощаются знаками, когда это превращается в единый, задуманный автором, знак в конце предложения: "?..",  "?!.".  А когда цитирующий исключает последние слова вопр./воскл. предложения, он ставит многоточие-купюру перед этими знаками. И вот здесь и встаёт вопрос, нужно/можно ли писать так: "..?", "..!" Исходя из того правила, я сделал для себя вывод, что нет: эти точки многоточия не должны поглощаться знаками: "...?"

Comment: А почему вы все время говорите про цитирование? А если это обычный диалог или просто текст? У Розенталя дается общее правило, про цитирование он ничего не говорит http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=180#pp180  И что за единый знак, какой у него смысл? Ну пауза после вопросительной интонации, что еще-то? Мне кажется, это просто графическая условность, чтобы точки не множить.

Comment: Да с этим всё понятно, я назвал его единым, поскольку объединяются два знака. А вот многоточие перед знаками говорит о пропуске слова/слов.